# Selecting two rows in a single sql statement only if both conditions are met

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, multiple-conditions

I've got a table with the following data.

> table name: myTable

```
prodID   catNo   variable1  variable2
1        20      Cat        Blue
2        10      Cat        Red
2        15      Cat        Green
2        20      Cat        Black
3        20      Cat        Yellow
4        10      Cat        Orange
4        15      Cat        Brown
4        20      Cat        Black
5        30      Cat        Pink
```

I want to be able to select all columns from myTable where the following is true
 "(**prodID = 2** and **catNo = 10**) AND (**prodID = 2** and **catNo = 15**)". Therefore getting a result of the two rows only if both conditions are met and it will return nothing if both rows aren't present.
So my results table will look like this.

> table name: results

```
prodID   catNo   variable1  variable2
2        10      Cat        Red
2        15      Cat        Green
```

I've tried to use conditional if statements but can't seem to get them working in the sql. My current solution it to get back all rows with prodID = 2 and then using php to do the if statement to decide what to display but this won't work with the pagination I've designed for displaying the results as my limit will distort the number of results per page.
I know I could use 'having count rows=2' but I'm not sure how to word it.

Comment: replace AND with OR it will works 

"(prodID = 2 and catNo = 10) OR (prodID = 2 and catNo = 15)".

Comment: `where prodID = 2 and (catNo = 10 OR catNo = 15)`?

Comment: To get the rows with more than 1 catNo: `SELECT *, COUNT(catNo) FROM myTable HAVING COUNT(catNo) > 1`

Comment: Sorry for posting this on every comment but most people don't seem to understand my request.<br/>Both conditions have to be true so "OR" isn't an option. That would return one result if the row with 'catNo =15' wasn't there. I need both rows only if they both exist.<br/>
 And having count(catNo)>1 will return all rows with more than 1 catNo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [M Khalid Junaid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919538/selecting-two-rows-in-a-single-sql-statement-only-if-both-conditions-are-met#answer-27919964) works. I've managed to come up with a solution that doesn't require a join which with a very large table like mine will be it would be rather slow:

```
select * 
from myTable 
where ((prodID = 2 and catNo = 10) or (prodID = 2 and catNo = 15)) 
group by catNo
having (
        select count(distinct(catNo))
        from myTable 
        where ((prodID = 2 and catNo = 10) or (prodID = 2 and catNo = 15))
)=2;
```

Comment: this way if in your database are 2 rows with catno=10 and not anyone with catno=15 you will get result since the count of the rows with catno=10 will be 2, which is not what you want as you say.

Comment: The combination of proID and catNo will be unique. But I understand what you're saying. If I have two rows with the values with prodID =2 and catNo = 10 but no row with prodID =2 and catNo = 15

Comment: @PeterDarmis I've taken into account for your point and have revised my solution. This works now if there are two rows with the same information.

Comment: @PeterDarmis Can remove the 'group by' if we're dealing with not unique combinations of 'prodID' and 'cat' but still require that there be a cat of 10 and a cat of 15 present in order to get 'all' rows back i.e. more than two.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get results only if records are found in catNo (10,15) but to also return 0 results if you where looking for catNo in (10,12)

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` 
WHERE (`prodID` = 2 AND `catNo` IN (10,15)) 
AND (SELECT COUNT(`catNo`) FROM `myTable` WHERE `prodID` = 2 AND `catNo` IN (10,15))>1;
```

For three CatNo's

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` 
WHERE (`prodID` = 4 AND `catNo` IN (10,15,20)) 
AND (SELECT COUNT(`catNo`) FROM `myTable` WHERE `prodID` = 4 AND `catNo` IN (10,15,20))>2;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f86e9/9)

Comment: Both conditions have to be true so "OR" isn't an option.
That would return one result if the row with 'catNo =15' wasn't there. I need both rows only if they both exist.

Comment: if there are no categories between the range og 10-15 for catNo then the 3rd example is the quickest solution.

Comment: That's not a workable solution as the variables will be user defined to build the results and could request only the rows where (prodID=2 and catNo=10) AND (prodID=2 and catNo=20).

This is just made up data, I couldn't actually put up data from my database.

Comment: XOR is one or the other but not both. I need both.

Comment: Nope, change the second variable from 15 to 12 and it returns 1 row instead of none. Sorry, thanks for still trying though.

Comment: Try now you can alter both catNo or prodID to test it. It will return what you want.

Comment: As I had previously stated in response to your comment on my solution "The combination of proID and catNo will be unique. But I understand what you're saying. If I have two rows with the values with prodID =2 and catNo = 10 but no row with prodID =2 and catNo = 15" it will return both rows with "prodID =2 and catNo = 10" this will happen for your solution now.

Comment: The edited answer covers the question in full i don't understand the down-vote sorry.

Comment: Because in your first solution if I have two row's that are (2,10) and no (2,15) it will return both (2,10)'s. 
It does not look for 2,10 and 2,15 it just looks for more than one row that has either 2,10 or 2,15.
This is not what was asked for. There are already solutions given that work for the requested problem and yours have never worked based on your observation. Your solution will only work if you guarantee that the prod/cat combination are unique.

Comment: @FiHoran that combination should be unique by default firstly, secondly just add a group by prod,cat and you are done. Thanks also for being so eager to  write that my answer doesn't work. There is an SQL fiddle below it with data from your question have you tried it? And last of all... ok mate whatever you say, if you don't like it don't use it. Someone else might find it better solution.

Comment: Group by if there were two (2,10) rows and one (2,15) would only return two rows not the three that exist.

Comment: Yes that would be done in case there where duplicate entries in your db. Remember your question, run the fiddle , the answer covers your question in full @FiHoran that is all sir. Nothing more to discuss from my part.

Answer (score 2):

To match both categories for same product you can do so

```
select t.*
from table1 t
join (
select prodID
from table1
where catNo in (10,15)
and prodID = 2
group by prodID
having count(distinct catNo ) = 2
  ) t2
using(prodID)
where t.catNo in (10,15)
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1234/4)

Comment: Thanks for all the effort and adding proof that your solution works, yours is the only solution that does what I've requested so far.
I've got another solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919538/selecting-two-rows-in-a-single-sql-statement-only-if-both-conditions-are-met#answer-27921258) without a join

Comment: I still can't get it around my head why this doesn't work WHERE (prodID = 2 and catNo = 10) AND (prodID = 2 and catNo = 15)? Can someone explain?

Comment: @OliverNilsen when filter is applied on rows one by one this clause is not satisfied because a single row can have one of these values not both at the same time

Answer (score 1):

Use the below SQL query.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable where prodID = 2 and (catNo = 10 OR catNo = 15)
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `prodID` = '2' AND `catNo` IN ('10','15')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a.*,b.catNo,c.catNo FROM myTable AS a
 JOIN mytable AS b ON b.prodID=a.prodID
 JOIN mytable AS c ON c.prodID=a.prodID
 WHERE a.prodID=2 AND b.catNo=10
 AND c.catNo=15;
```

this one worked. really tricky situation this problem is.

Comment: I've run yours here and I get all three rows containing prodID=2 due to the joins. You get the same if you say "SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM myTable AS a"
[http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a8fe/6](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6a8fe/6)

Answer (score 0):

Most solutions posted are missing the part about returning nothing unless BOTH where conditions are met.  As such most solutions will fail if one and only one condition is met, as they will still return one row instead of none.

Assuming you want to be able to check for any number of WHERE conditions, and not just two, you could use a sub query based solution.

Using this approach you can check the number of qualifying rows within the result set prior to output.  There are a few ways to do this but the idea is to compare the number of qualifying rows against your expected number of rows.  If they match, output the rows.  If they do not match, return an empty result set.

M Khalid Junaid has posted a solution using a group by with a having condition within a sub query to check that the result set size is 2.  This solution will work for your specific example and others like it.  It might not if your WHERE conditions become more complex or varied as it relies on ProdID being the same in each WHERE condition, but the principal is sound.  Also, this particular method requires the WHERE condition be processed against the source table twice, whereas the one below only does so once.  For very large tables and/or many WHERE conditions this method should be more efficient.

You can construct sub queries either directly in the FROM condition as in other examples, or via WITH statements.  I've used the later here as it more clearly shows what is going on:

```
With ResultSet as (select * from myTable
        where (prodID = 2 AND catNo = 10) OR (prodID = 2 AND catNo = 15)), -- your WHERE condition
    TotalRows as (select COUNT(*) as TRows from ResultSet) -- count of result set
select ResultSet.*
from ResultSet
    inner join TotalRows on 1=1 -- force the join to work no matter what the tables contain
where TRows = 2 -- this is where you check against how many result rows you expect
```

The "ResultSet" sub query is where your WHERE cause goes, and it can be as simple or complex as required.  "TotalRows" counts the result set, and therefore contains only one row.  You then join the sub queries together but only output rows from the former if the result set count (TRows) matches your expected row size from the later.

Answer (score 0):

You can try writing a function. It's quite long but quite easy to understand

```
DROP FUNCTION getIt();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getIt()
RETURNS TABLE (prodID INTEGER, catNo INTEGER, variable1 TEXT, variable2 TEXT) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  IF (CAST ((SELECT "prodID" 
     FROM "myTable" 
     where "prodID"=2 and "catNo" = 10) AS INTEGER)>0 AND CAST ((SELECT "prodID" 
     FROM "myTable" 
     where "prodID"=2 and "catNo" = 15) AS INTEGER)>0)
  THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT * 
     FROM "myTable" 
     where "prodID"=2 and ("catNo" = 10 or "catNo" = 15 );
  END IF;
END;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
SELECT * FROM getIt();
```

It can be parameterized

```
DROP FUNCTION getIt(pid integer, cid1 integer, cid2 integer);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getIt(pid integer, cid1 integer, cid2 integer)
RETURNS TABLE (prodID INTEGER, catNo INTEGER, variable1 TEXT, variable2 TEXT) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
  IF (CAST ((SELECT "prodID" 
     FROM "myTable" 
     where "prodID"=$1 and "catNo" = $2) AS INTEGER)>0 AND CAST ((SELECT "prodID" 
     FROM "myTable" 
     where "prodID"=$1 and "catNo" = $3) AS INTEGER)>0)
  THEN RETURN QUERY SELECT * 
     FROM "myTable" 
     where "prodID"=$1 and ("catNo" = $2 or "catNo" = $3 );
  END IF;
END;
$BODY$ 
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
SELECT * FROM getIt(2, 10, 15);
```

Comment: Can you document more of what this function is designed to do and how it is doing it?

Comment: This function is designed for taking proper content from table myTable for given parameter values. It returns those two desired rows in a case that we have both rows in a table.

Answer (score -2):

The condition should be (prodID = 2 and catNo = 10) OR (prodID = 2 and catNo = 15)

Comment: the result is not was the op expected.... he will prodID's which has catNo=10 and catNo=15 *Therefore getting a result of the two rows only if both conditions are met*

Comment: Both conditions have to be true so "OR" isn't an option.

Comment: select * from mytable where prodid in (select prodid from mytable where catno = 10 ) and prodid in (select prodid from mytable where catno = 15 )